# upper envelope of data

Tags: data, envelope

Here is a `ListPlot[]` of some data. Clearly, there is a fairly smooth upper envelope - the question is whether there is an nice way of extracting it...

[image]

Comment: Why not start with a maximizing over a moving window, and then smooth the result? Also, if you could send the data (or a small subset of it) it would be hlepful

Comment: Check out `MaxFilter`.

Comment: Use ConvexHull[] on the reciprocals.

Comment: @EricTowers This will work for a convex envelope like this, but not in general.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

One could imagine a more detailed question (e.g. with data, and a clear statement of whether it is the upper points, or a function, that is wanted).

Here is an approach to this.

First set up an example.

```
pts = RandomReal[{1, 5}, {10^4, 2}];
pts2 = Select[pts, #[[1]]*#[[2]] <= 5 &];
pts2 // Length
ListPlot[pts2]
```

[image]

We use an internal function to extract the envelope points.

```
upper = -Internal`ListMin[-pts2];
Length[upper]
ListPlot[upper]

(* Out[212]= 111 *)
```

[image]

Now guess a formula.

```
FindFormula[upper]

(* Out[209]= 4.92582954108/#1 & *)
```

More generally if one has in mind say a small set of monomials and wants to find an algebraic relation amongst the points, then there are various fitting functions that can be used.

Comment: I am not sure what the significance of "Internal" is. Does it mean that this is something that could change at any moment?

Comment: In theory yes. In this example, no. It is somethig we have used for the better part of a decade in FrobeniusNumber code and maybe elsewhere. For the life of me I don't know why it has not been promoted to `System` context. Uses the Bentley-Clarkson-Levine algorithm, by the way.

Answer (score 29):

This is an almost perfect application for [Quantile Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression). (See [these blog posts](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/?s=QuantileRegression) for Quantile Regression implementations and applications in Mathematica.)

Here is some data (as in Daniel Lichtblau's answer):

```
pts = RandomReal[{1, 5}, {10^4, 2}];
pts2 = Select[pts, #[[1]]*#[[2]] <= 5 &];
pts2 // Length
ListPlot[pts2]
```

[image]

Load the package QuantileRegression.m:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/QuantileRegression.m"]
```

Apply Quantile Regression (using a basis of five B-splines of order 3) so that 99% of the points are below the regression quantile curve:

```
qFunc = QuantileRegression[pts2, 5, {0.99}][[1]];
```

Plot the result:

```
Show[{
  ListPlot[pts2],
  Plot[qFunc[x], {x, Min[pts2[[All, 1]]], Max[pts2[[All, 1]]]}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Here is how the function looks like:

```
qFunc[x] // Simplify
```

[image]

Using Quantile Regression also works in more complicated cases:

```
pts = RandomReal[{0, 3 Pi}, 20000];
pts = Transpose[{pts, RandomReal[{0, 20}, Length[pts]]}];
pts2 = Select[pts, Sin[#[[1]]/2] + 2 + Cos[2*#[[1]]] >= #[[2]] &];
Length[pts2]
ListPlot[pts2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
qFunc = QuantileRegression[pts2, 16, {0.996}][[1]];

Show[{
  ListPlot[pts2],
  Plot[qFunc[x], {x, Min[pts2[[All, 1]]], Max[pts2[[All, 1]]]}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

(I was not able to obtain good results using `` Internal`ListMin `` in this case.)

Answer (score 10):

Since this question has popped up again, here is a way to use MaxFilter followed by smoothing with a GaussianFilter.

```
pts = RandomReal[{1, 5}, {10^4, 2}];
pts2 = Select[pts, #[[1]]*#[[2]] <= 5 &];
{xs, ys} = Transpose[Sort[pts2, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &]];
Show[{ListPlot[pts2], 
  ListLinePlot[Transpose[{xs, GaussianFilter[MaxFilter[ys, 50], 50]}],
    PlotStyle -> Red]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice and simple (+1). Also, works fairly well for the second dataset in my answer -- see [this image](http://i.imgur.com/5Vt8Qi8.png). (And it is much faster...)

Answer (score 6):

Just for record by a function used in this site rarely:`EstimatedBackground`

```
pts = RandomReal[{1, 5}, {10^4, 2}];
pts2 = Select[pts, #[[1]]*#[[2]] <= 5 &];
ListPlot[pts2]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[-EstimatedBackground[-Reverse@
     SortBy[pts2, Last][[All, 2]]], 
 DataRange -> MinMax[pts2[[All, 1]]], Epilog -> {Red, Point[pts2]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting solution! Unfortunately, does not seem to be working for even slightly different data. E.g. `pts2 = Select[pts, #[[1]]*#[[2]] <= 2 &]`.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Thanks for your foresight.The answer's code to should adjust to be`-EstimatedBackground[-Reverse@SortBy[pts2,Last][[All,2]],25]` to fit your `pts2`.It seems that I this way is not so good to do this.