# How to find the boundary points of a list of points in a plot

Tags: computational-geometry

If I plot a group of points like the one below, how do I differentiate and extract say the points on the bottom boundary? What about 3 dimensions?

[image]

Comment: Interesting question! Would you please provide the code for the shown example?

Comment: I guess it should be easy to adapt [upper envelope of data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94770/5478)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher My code is most complicated and generate a large number of points, I don't know how to encapsulate them:<

Comment: @Kuba The example you provided seems to not extract the boundary points but only to fit a proper function as boundary?

Comment: @updraft not really, while answers aim in providing a smooth result, most of them has an intermediate step of extracting the envelope. btw, search around 'envelope points' and similar keywords, there are few related topics.

Comment: @Kuba yes I see your point, thank you for the info!