# Interpolation function

Tags: plotting, interpolation

I am facing a problem in getting a smooth plot of following data.

```
DD := {{{0, 0}, 1}, {{0, 0.1}, 1}, {{0, 0.2}, 1}, {{0, 0.3}, 
1}, {{0, 0.4}, 1}, {{0, 0.5}, 1}, {{0, 0.6}, 1}, {{0, 0.7}, 
1}, {{0, 0.736}, 1}, {{0.2, 0.0}, 0.997978}, {{0.2, 0.1}, 
0.99592}, {{0.2, 0.2}, 0.994118}, {{0.2, 0.3}, 
0.99321}, {{0.2, 0.4}, 0.990521}, {{0.2, 0.5}, 
0.990098}, {{0.2, 0.6}, 0.981427}, {{0.2, 0.684}, 
0.954755}, {{0.3, 0}, 0.99357}, {{0.3, 0.3}, 
0.985479}, {{0.3, 0.628105}, 0.927041}, {{0.4, 0}, 
0.991344}, {{0.4, 0.1}, 0.988842}, {{0.4, 0.3}, 
0.980593}, {{0.4, 0.4}, 0.972082}, {{0.4, 0.5573}, 
0.900049}, {{0.5, 0.0}, 0.98288}, {{0.5, 0.1}, 
0.979876}, {{0.5, 0.2}, 0.972208}, {{0.5, 0.3}, 
0.964005}, {{0.5, 0.4}, 0.943466}, {{0.5, 0.465}, 
0.914242}, {{0.6, 0}, 0.976438}, {{0.6, 0.1}, 
0.967633}, {{0.6, 0.2}, 0.960438}, {{0.6, 0.38848}, 
0.876153}, {{0.7, 0.0}, 0.96334}, {{0.7, 0.1}, 
0.953086}, {{0.7, 0.2}, 0.935014}, {{0.7, 0.2952}, 
0.874474}, {{0.8, 0}, 0.952486}, {{0.8, 0.1}, 
0.933406}, {{0.8, 0.198}, 0.874677}, {{0.9, 0}, 
0.928887}, {{0.9, 0.09983}, 0.866017}}

f = Interpolation[DD, InterpolationOrder -> 16];
ContourPlot[Quiet[Check[f[a, g], Null]], {a, 0, 0.9}, {g, 0, 0.75}, 
PlotLegends -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

I am getting a rough plot on using Mathematica 9. I am looking to get a smooth plot.
[image]
Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Did any of the answers satisfied your need? There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. One weeks is enough wait. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Comment: @rhermans. Yes, suggestions for this problem worked for me. Many thanks to all.

Answer (score 6):

At least in version 11.3 when `Interpolation` is called there is the error

> Interpolation::udeg: Interpolation on unstructured grids is currently only supported for InterpolationOrder->1 or InterpolationOrder->All. Order will be reduced to 1.

Using `InterpolationOrder -> All` and appropriate `PlotRange` fixes the plot:

```
DD = {{{0,0},1},{{0,0.1},1},{{0,0.2},1},{{0,0.3},1},{{0,0.4},1},{{0,0.5},1},
      {{0,0.6},1},{{0,0.7},1},{{0,0.736},1},{{0.2,0.0},0.997978},{{0.2,0.1},0.99592},
      {{0.2,0.2},0.994118},{{0.2,0.3},0.99321},{{0.2,0.4},0.990521},{{0.2,0.5},0.990098},
      {{0.2,0.6},0.981427},{{0.2,0.684},0.954755},{{0.3,0},0.99357},{{0.3,0.3},0.985479},
      {{0.3,0.628105},0.927041},{{0.4,0},0.991344},{{0.4,0.1},0.988842},{{0.4,0.3},0.980593},
      {{0.4,0.4},0.972082},{{0.4,0.5573},0.900049},{{0.5,0.0},0.98288},{{0.5,0.1},0.979876},
      {{0.5,0.2},0.972208},{{0.5,0.3},0.964005},{{0.5,0.4},0.943466},{{0.5,0.465},0.914242},
      {{0.6,0},0.976438},{{0.6,0.1},0.967633},{{0.6,0.2},0.960438},{{0.6,0.38848},0.876153},
      {{0.7,0.0},0.96334},{{0.7,0.1},0.953086},{{0.7,0.2},0.935014},{{0.7,0.2952},0.874474},
      {{0.8,0},0.952486},{{0.8,0.1},0.933406},{{0.8,0.198},0.874677},{{0.9,0},0.928887},
      {{0.9,0.09983},0.866017}};

f = Interpolation[DD, InterpolationOrder -> All];

ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 0.9}, {y, 0, 0.75}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50,
              PlotRange -> {All, All, {-0.4, 1.4}}, Contours -> Range[-4/10, 12/10, 1/5]]
```

[image]

In V10 `ConvexHullMesh` can be used to specify the plot region (because your data supports every edge of its convex hull):

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ ConvexHullMesh[DD[[All, 1]]], 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**Edit:** In V9 you can use the order 1 interpolation as a region function:

```
fDom = Interpolation[DD, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
f = Interpolation[DD, InterpolationOrder -> All];

ContourPlot[If[Check[fDom[a, g], True] =!= True, f[a, g], Null], {a, 0, 0.9}, {g, 0, 0.75},
         PlotLegends -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> 1, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> All]
```

In 11.3 the output is practically the same as that of the `ConvexHullMesh` version.

**Edit:** Maybe using a fit is better:

```
fit[x_, y_] = Normal[LinearModelFit[Append @@@ DD, x^# y^#2 & @@@ Tuples[{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, 2], {x, y}]];
fDom = Interpolation[DD, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
ContourPlot[If[Check[fDom[a, g], True] =!= True, fit[a, g], Null], {a, 0, 0.9}, {g, 0, 0.75},
   PlotRange -> {All, All, {0.86, 1.02}},
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 1,
   Contours -> (Rescale[#, {Min[#], Max[#]}, {0.84, 1}] &[Range[20] // Sqrt])]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggestions..Actually I am looking to get smoother version of plot that I show. I checked interpolation order is not changing the smoothness except interpolationorder->All. The plots that you are showing are not surving my purpose. Thanks again.

Comment: @Rahulkumarwalia I added another approach

Comment: Thanks. In fDom function why we can not have interpolation order higher than 1.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Version 11.3, but I hope the code below would produce similar results for you in Version 9.

```
dd = Flatten /@ {{{0, 0}, 1}, {{0, 0.1}, 1}, {{0, 0.2}, 1}, {{0, 0.3},
      1}, {{0, 0.4}, 1}, {{0, 0.5}, 1}, {{0, 0.6}, 1}, {{0, 0.7}, 
     1}, {{0, 0.736}, 1}, {{0.2, 0.0}, 0.997978}, {{0.2, 0.1}, 
     0.99592}, {{0.2, 0.2}, 0.994118}, {{0.2, 0.3}, 
     0.99321}, {{0.2, 0.4}, 0.990521}, {{0.2, 0.5}, 
     0.990098}, {{0.2, 0.6}, 0.981427}, {{0.2, 0.684}, 
     0.954755}, {{0.3, 0}, 0.99357}, {{0.3, 0.3}, 
     0.985479}, {{0.3, 0.628105}, 0.927041}, {{0.4, 0}, 
     0.991344}, {{0.4, 0.1}, 0.988842}, {{0.4, 0.3}, 
     0.980593}, {{0.4, 0.4}, 0.972082}, {{0.4, 0.5573}, 
     0.900049}, {{0.5, 0.0}, 0.98288}, {{0.5, 0.1}, 
     0.979876}, {{0.5, 0.2}, 0.972208}, {{0.5, 0.3}, 
     0.964005}, {{0.5, 0.4}, 0.943466}, {{0.5, 0.465}, 
     0.914242}, {{0.6, 0}, 0.976438}, {{0.6, 0.1}, 
     0.967633}, {{0.6, 0.2}, 0.960438}, {{0.6, 0.38848}, 
     0.876153}, {{0.7, 0.0}, 0.96334}, {{0.7, 0.1}, 
     0.953086}, {{0.7, 0.2}, 0.935014}, {{0.7, 0.2952}, 
     0.874474}, {{0.8, 0}, 0.952486}, {{0.8, 0.1}, 
     0.933406}, {{0.8, 0.198}, 0.874677}, {{0.9, 0}, 
     0.928887}, {{0.9, 0.09983}, 0.866017}};

ListPointPlot3D[dd, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

At this point I try to device some function for `ContourPlot`'s option `RegionPlot`. I am using `` Internal`ListMin `` from this discussion: ["upper envelope of data"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94777/34008).
***(I assume the function `ListMin` is also available in Version 9.)***

```
upper = -Internal`ListMin[-Map[Most, dd]];
ListPlot[upper]
```

[image]

```
fb = Interpolation[upper, InterpolationOrder -> 2];

f = Interpolation[dd, InterpolationOrder -> All];

ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 0.9}, {y, 0, 0.75}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 120, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", PlotRange -> All, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 0 <= y <= fb[x]]]
```

[image]